# How to listen for Tapped event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I have the following sample function code to be called when the user Tap on a word and then tapped event should occur to Unhighlight that selected text.But in Javascript there is no such event.

```
 deleteHighlight:function(){
    var element = contentDoc.getElementsByClassName('highlighted');
    element.style.backgroundColor = "white";  
}
```

How to listen for that event and handle the same when the user tap on that word.?

any help is highly appreciated.

**Note**:No jquery please.I want this to be done only in javascript

Comment: are you using some framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `touchstart` when the word is being tapped and `touchend` in order to return to original state

`http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#idl-def-TouchEvent`

Comment: the event handler is called `touchstart` so just add and event listener and a callback function.